# Php: remove all tags, but "a href" in a text

Tags: php, filtering

Here's my problem:

I have a textarea where the user can enter whatever he wants.

When he sends this text (POST method), on the server side I don't filter it ***at all*** before writing it into the database (because I want to keep "intact" what the user entered (maybe it can be used as a proof he tried to hack or whatever)).

Then, before outputting it, I use this function:

```
public function textForWeb($texte,$br=true)
{
  if ($br) {
    return
      mb_ereg_replace("((\r)?\n)", "<br />",
        htmlentities(
          stripslashes($texte),
          ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'
        )
      );
  }
  else {
    return
      htmlentities(
        stripslashes($texte),
        ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'
      );
  }
}
```

So the text is properly filtered and stays `UTF-8` encoded.

But the problem is that I'd like ***all*** these text: `<a href="http://url">xxx</a>` to be untouched. I.e. when I will display it, the link (and only links with "`http://`" and ***no javascript inside***) will be "clickable".

For example, you can see how it is displayed now [here](http://www.papdevis.fr/devis-detail/offre/concepteur-developpeur-informatique/numero-3714362/). See last line of the announce? I'd like the link to the website to be "clickable".

How would you do?

Comment: Why not to use strip_tags() ? This doesn't solve javascript liks, but still a single function. After strip tags tou can remove all href attributes witout http. With regex probably.

Comment: Yes, but if removing only `href="(?!http)` then it isnt so bad. It could ruin syntax, but olny for that link, and javascript probably couldn't excecute. NOTE: this regex i gave, maybe not work, didnt test it.

Comment: I need it to convert everything apart from `<a>` tags into entities and to filter properly the `<a>` tags so that I can be sure it's only a valid URL (= no `JavaScript`)

Comment: Then your solution requires dom parsing and this could be really slow. If using dom parsing, then it's better to this on insert, not when displaying. And if you want to store original code to, then you could either store it in anothet table, or to 2 fields 'message' and 'message_original'. Let me know if you need addition information

Comment: Actually tom offered a prtty good solution ;)

Comment: @OlivierPons Updated my answer so that only links starting with http:// or https:// is converted back. Should work perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a preg_replace() function to revert the escaped **a** tags after your htmlentities() function

```
$output = textForWeb($output);
$output = preg_replace('#&lt;a href=&quot;(?=https:\/\/|http:\/\/)(.*?)&quot;&gt;(.*?)&lt;/a&gt;#i', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $output);

echo $output;
```

That way you can still escape all other HTML in a safe way (instead of using strip_tags() function.)

This preg_replace() function searches for **a** tags linking to pages starting with http:// or https:// and then replaces the escaped special characters with <, > and ", making the link clickable again.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and check if it's valid, thanks a lot =)

Comment: I'm working on it. Actually I think I'll convert to HTML entities, then I'll change myself URLs I consider "valid", i.e. for example if I see " `http://wwW.m.com/` " I'll add the `a href` tag around it so that it will be "clickable"

Comment: Anyway your answer is a great inspiration, so I mark it as valid.

Comment: @OlivierPons Ok, great! Thanks :) Good luck with your scripts!

Answer (score 1):

When outputting surely you'd be better just using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and setting "a" to be an allowable element?

I.e.

```
$string = strip_tags($string,'<a>');
```

This would remove the tags instead of converting them to their entities though. It depends if you need it to convert everything apart from `<a>` tags into entities, or if you just want to remove the code.

Comment: I need it to convert everything apart from `<a>` tags into entities and to filter properly the `<a>` tags so that I can be sure it's only a valid URL (= no JavaScript)

Comment: strip_tags() isn't sufficient for escaping HTML etc, you should always use htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, $text_encoding) when possible, or use htmlPurifier or something similar