# php regex to remove html tags but keep <a href

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php: remove all tags, but “a href” in a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908944/php-remove-all-tags-but-a-href-in-a-text)

Is there any way to strip out html tags using regex from a string but only keep the  tag and associated styling?

For example:

```
<div>
    <p>Blah blah blah <a href="xyz.com" style="blah blah">blah blah</a> blah blah</p>   </div>
```

will give you:

```
Blah blah blah <a href="xyz.com" style="blah blah">blah blah</a> blah blah
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does it really need to be regexp? Isn't `strip_tags` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `strip_tags` function with the second parameter:

```
$new_string = strip_tags($input_string, "<a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need regex for that, you can use strip_tags with the second parameter

Comment: the problem is that if you want to secure user input this is not the solution.. they can still use evil scripts by using tag attributes

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `preg_replace_callback` with the following regex:

```
$regex = "/<(\S+)[^>\\/]*(?:\\/>|>(.*)</\\1>)/msi";
```

This will select all tags. Now, you have to check in the callback, and if the contents of the group `1` is not `a` or `A`, you can return the contents of group `2` (inside the tag) otherwise return group `0` (no modifications).

Comment: You can further enhance this to match your needs by parsing the attributes of the tag using regex when encountering an anchor tag to see if malevolent attributes exist or not.